# Please Specify a Shipping Method error on submit order on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I have onetep checkout extension and sagepay extension installed.

```
1. Add product to cart...
 2. go to checkout page...
 3. select shipping method and payment method(sage pay)...
 4. Then click to 'place order' button...
```

It opens popup for sage pay detail. I enter sage pay test detail and click to submit, it gives error in js popup 'Please specify a shipping method'.

On file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php 
there is _validate() method which returns $method and $rate blank.

```
$method= $address->getShippingMethod();
$rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);
if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && (!$method || !$rate)) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Please specify a shipping method.'));
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Please share your solution - if it exists ;) We are having the same exact problem

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you have a product that's not virtual.